# How to apply style in GeoServer REST API

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

My goal is to updade style through the REST API.

My question is, how to apply style through REST API.

When I am updating existed style via rest API, it only updates content.
It needs to be applied for loading style on layer.
My code below:

This command is just updating the content of style but does not apply to layer

```
 curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: 'application/vnd.geoserver.geocss+css" -d @data_clone.css http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sde/styles/style_clone.css
```

It updates CSS fie but does not update SLD file

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what happened? what went wrong?

Comment: I have edited post.